# JQuery Slider doesn't get its values updated correctly when called dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I'm calling container.slider(...) dynamically and only getting the correct look when it gets called for the first time. How do I fix it?

Update - Clearly the demo is a quick hack reproducing the problem, let's not pick at using global vars etc unless it relates to the problem.

Repro (press the button a few times):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/external/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/external/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //
            var longValues = [10, 50, 90];
            var shortValues = [50];
            var mode;

            function setLong() {
                $("#c").slider({ orientation: "horizontal", range: false, values: longValues, min: 0, max: 100, step: 1 });
                mode = "long";
            }

            function setShort() {
                $("#c").slider({ orientation: "horizontal", range: false, values: shortValues, min: 0, max: 100, step: 1 });
                mode = "short";
            }


            $("#t").on("click", function () {


                if (mode == "long") {
                    console.log("set short");
                    setShort();

                }
                else {
                    console.log("set long");
                    setLong();
                }
            });

            setLong();

        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;">

   <div id="c" style="width: 200px; vertical-align: middle;">
   </div>

   <button id="t">Toggle
   </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add and remove two of the handles when clicking the button ?

Comment: No. I'm trying to render a different slider in the same container.

Comment: Well, here's how you'd do that -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qAweP/) ...

Comment: Superb. I thought that the old slider gets destroyed just by the virtue of calling container.slider(...), but that wasn't enough obviously. Could you post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing the number of handles, it seems the old handles are not removed, and to "reset" the slider, you probably have to destroy it first:

```
function setLong() {
    $("#c").slider( "destroy" );
    $("#c").slider({ orientation: "horizontal", 
                           range: false, 
                          values: longValues, 
                             min: 0, 
                             max: 100, 
                            step: 1 
    });
    mode = "long";
}
```

This seems to work, but there could be issues with destroying and initializing sliders like this, and it's not really properly tested or anything.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qAweP/)

Comment: Who could have thunk the "destroy" isn't called from within slider()? Surely whenever you call slider() you want to get a brand new slider as opposed to a mutated version of the previous one...

Comment: You'd think it works like that, and you really do get a new slider, but that's just a few elements being appended, and the old elements are'nt removed, that's why you need to call destroy whenever you need a new slider on the same element. you can also change the slider by calling `$(element).slider('options', 'min', 100)`, but that does'nt remove the old handles when changing the values either (tried it).

Comment: that's right but I might change my slider completely - orientation, min/max, values - it's just so much easier to re-init it in one go by calling slider(). Why would you ever call slider() without calling destroy first, that's what it gets me:)

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the functions setShort() and setLong() and the variables from the document.ready scope and into the global.

The functions and variables only exist during the execution of the document.ready handler. After that anonymous function executes, any variables and functions inside cease to exist. By moving the variables and functions outside of the document.ready anonymous function, they will   exist indefinitely.

Comment: what a nonsense, my friend.